# How to run JavaScript right when a component has been fully rendered in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I want to run some JavaScript that would increase the width of a div. When using:

```
document.getElementId("bouncyBox")
```

in the index.html root file, it returns null because the index.html (app root) runs first and then the component (home component). I am trying to see if I can detect which component renders, so I can runs some JavaScript for that specific component that has the div named bouncyBox.

I used:

```
ng new public
```

to build the file structure/project. What I use to build the components:

```
ng genereate component component_name
```

-it will create four files (CSS, HTML, spect.ts, ts)

This is my intention once I am able to get a hold of the HTML element.

```
<div class = "homeCom">
   <p>Home Component</p>
   <div id = "bouncyBox">
      <p>bouncyBox the </p>
   </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   console.log("helleo chinck")
   var myBox = document.getElementById("bouncyBox");
   console.log("Hererere, ", myBox)
   if (document.getElementById("bouncyBox")){
   console.log("hjelo");
   var w = 20;
   var h = 20;
   var mutateDiv = setInterval(function () {
      if(w>500) clearInterval(mutateDiv)
      w = w + 5;
      h = h + 5;
      document.getElementById("bouncyBox").style.width = w + 'px';
      document.getElementById("bouncyBox").style.height = h + 'px';
   }, 1000);
}
</script>
```

As stated before, because the index.html runs first and then the component, document.getElementBy("bouncyBox") will return null. The JavaScript that I am trying to run is in the index.html. I have tried to place the JavaScript in the HTML file of the component, but it's not being read.

index.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Public</title>
        <base href="/">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class = "wrapper">
            <app-root></app-root>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the app.component.html with is within the app-root

```html
<div class = "upperBar">
    <ul>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/']">Home</a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/Portfolio']">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/About']">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div class = "contact">
    <h2>Email and Sockit.IO</h2>
</div>
<div class = "lowerbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">GitHub</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Linkedin</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: write the js in component's controller?

Comment: looks like Angular2 [angular] not an angularjs question to me = you're looking for afterviewinit ?

Comment: No I am using angular js. When using ng genereate component component_name, it will create four files(css, html, spect.ts, ts) Then to render a component, the app-routing.module.ts file will be used. (Not sure if angular 2 uses the same method.) @AkberIqbal

Comment: simple setTimeout, $timeout? U need to provide more details in question

Comment: Just updated the question, hope its clear. Thank you.@PetrAveryanov @Supercool